# Something wrong with mock method to throw exception use Powermock and TestNG

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, testng, powermock

I want to test the method that has two catch branches, like this:

```
try {
        checkJobTypeIsExpired(jobType);
        if (FieldServiceCloudConstant.JOB_TYPE_DISPATCH == jobType) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = dispatchPlatformHelper.staffList((Integer) param.get("pageNo"), (Integer) param.get("pageSize"), dateType, date, businessWebContext);
            processorResult.setData(jsonObject);
        }
    } catch (PaasException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        processorResult.setStatusCode(e.getErrorCode());
        processorResult.setMessage(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        processorResult.setStatusCode(e.getErrorCode());
        processorResult.setMessage(e.getMessage());
    }
```

I want to cover all catch branches, so I wrote two test methods, like this:

```
@Test
public void staffListThrowPaasException() throws Exception {
    Map<String,Object> param=new HashMap();
    param.put("jobType",1);
    param.put("date",2L);
    param.put("dateType","day");
    param.put("groupId",2L);
    PowerMockito.when(dispatchPlatformHelper, "staffList", Mockito.anyInt(),Mockito.anyInt(),Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyLong(),Mockito.any(BusinessWebContext.class)).thenThrow(paasException);
    ProcessorResult processorResult = dispatchPlatformBusinessServiceImpl.staffList(param,businessWebContext);
    Assert.assertEquals(processorResult.getStatusCode(),CodeMessage.SERVER_ERROR.getCode());
}

@Test
public void staffListThrowServiceException() throws Exception {
    Map<String,Object> param=new HashMap();
    param.put("jobType",1);
    param.put("date",1L);
    param.put("dateType","day");
    param.put("groupId",1L);
    PowerMockito.when(dispatchPlatformHelper, "staffList", Mockito.anyInt(),Mockito.anyInt(),Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyLong(),Mockito.any(BusinessWebContext.class)).thenThrow(serviceException);
    ProcessorResult processorResult = dispatchPlatformBusinessServiceImpl.staffList(param,businessWebContext);
    Assert.assertEquals(processorResult.getStatusCode(),CodeMessage.SERVER_ERROR.getCode());
}
```

In these two test methods, I use PowerMock to mock `staffList` method that belong to `DispatchPlatformHelper` class to throw different exception for cover two catch branches that I mentioned above.

`staffListThrowPaasException()` and `staffListThrowServiceException()` work correctly when I run their individually. but When I use `testng.xml` run their orderly, the last test method will fail. when run to `PowerMockito.when(dispatchPlatformHelper, "staffList", Mockito.anyInt(),Mockito.anyInt(),Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyLong(),Mockito.any(BusinessWebContext.class)).thenThrow(serviceException);`
 in the `staffListThrowServiceException()` method, it will throw `InvocationTargetException` exception, and will jump to the line 466 code of `Invoker` class that in `testng-6.10.jar`.
[image]

So, I want to know that why, and how to accomplish my situation? THX

Comment: What is the exact stacktrace you're getting?

Comment: @Morfic no exception informations, just test fail.

Comment: When you say fail, you mean an `assertion fail`? If yes, what's the message? Also it would be helpful if you could provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org) to reproduce it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your code is **not** showing where dispatchPlatformHelper is initialized.

Comment: @YuXuanFu - If you are running via a testng xml file, then I would suggest that you please add `verbose="2"` (or a higher value) to the `<suite>` tag. This would cause TestNG to start dumping the stacktrace on the console and help you with debugging.